# Determine angle of rotation for a skewed 2D image

Tags: python, image-processing, rotation, pose-estimation

I am trying to determine the angle of rotation required to fix the skew seen in a 2D image. I have a camera that is looking at a QR code taped to a wall. I am trying to find out how the camera should rotate left and right so that the camera is facing the qr code straight on.

Assuming the y axis is the axis running up and down and x axis is left to right, if my camera is to the left of the qr code, then my code should instruct the camera to rotate around the y axis by a certain number of degrees so that it ends up facing the qr code straight on. I have the coordinates of the four corners of the qr code. I also know that the camera is sitting to the left of the qr code since the vertical qr code side closest to the camera is longer than the opposite vertical side (i.e. the qr code is skewed in the image being processed).

I don't know how to find the angle though. Any help is appreciated! Image below shows qr code, and it's bounding box (x,y) points.

[image]

Comment: The QR codes I've worked with also have one of the corners distinct from the others. You say you have the four corners, can you also identify which of the four the "special" corner is? What I'm referring to is usually the lower right corner of the code.

Comment: I've added an image of the qr code which shows the coordinates of each corner of the qr code. I'm not sure what you mean by a "special" corner though.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is exactly what you need, I'm assuming your end goal is to extract the QR code from the image so that it can be decoded. If you're using open CV this can be done easily with ```cv2.getPerspectiveTransform``` to get the transformation matrix, and then ```cv2.warpPerspective``` to cut out the QR code from the image.

Comment: I'm already able to decode the qr code. My goal is to be able to tell the camera how to rotate so it views the qr code straight on. I thought of using getPerspectiveTransform, but I don't know how to decompose the transformation matrix into individual rotation angles about each axis and individual translations along x, y and z. I need to be able to tell a motor attached to the camera to move right by this many inches or rotate around a certain axis by so many degrees in order to face the qr code head on.